# Is it possible to send a custom http request header when using dojox form iframe

Tags: http, post, iframe, dojo

I have a Dojo UI that allows file uploads. Everything is fine when using the HTML5 dojo uploader. One of my requirements is that I need to include a security token in the HTTP request header. When using IE9, the dojo uploader uses _IFRAME. I can't figure out a way to pass that security token as part of the HTTP request header. Looks like _IFRAME will create a

```
'<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"></form>'
```

element which is used for doing the file upload. Not sure how to solve this issue based on the fact that i need to pass that custom token on the request header.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use `dojo/request/xhr` for the uploading part. Check out the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request/xhr.html). You can use the `headers` property to add your custom token to the headers.